# debug javascript code to calculate average then assign letter grade

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate average of values for var 1 and average for values for var 2 in a dbase table.  I also want to assign a letter grade to the average.  My script pretends that it's working and is even assigning a letter grade in the output, but the calculation is incorrect.  Can you help me to debug?

```
var correspondence = "FDCBAA"; // last A is for a perfect 5
var courtesyVal = 0, overallVal = 0;    

if (data.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        courtesyVal += data[i].grade_courtesy;
        overallVal += data[i].grade_overall;
    }

    courtesyVal = (courtesyVal / data.length);
    overallVal = (overallVal / data.length);
}

courtesyVal = correspondence[Math.floor(courtesyVal)];
overallVal = correspondence[Math.floor(overallVal)];

if (courtesyVal >= 4 || overallVal >= 4) {
    courtesyVal = "A";
    overallVal = "A";
} 
else if (courtesyVal >= 3 || overallVal >= 3) {
    courtesyVal = "B";
    overallVal = "B";
} 
else if (courtesyVal >= 2 || overallVal >= 2) {
    courtesyVal = "C";
    overallVal = "C";
} 
else if (courtesyVal >= 1 || overallVal >= 1) {
    courtesyVal = "D"; 
    overallVal = "D";
} 
else {
    courtesyVal = "F"; 
    overallVal = "F";
}
Appery("courtesy_grade").text(courtesyVal);
Appery("overall_grade").text(overallVal);
```

Comment: Could you provide an example for what your `data` array would look like?

Comment: My data is in a simple table into which the UI will continuously feed values.  Multiple variables, but I'm only calculating average on 2 of the variables.  [grade_courtesy and grade_overall]

incident_state
(string) 
citizen_age
(string) 
citizen_input
(string) 
legit
(string) 
why_stop
(string) 
grade_courtesy
(number) 
grade_overall
(number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that your lines:

```
courtesyVal = correspondence[Math.floor(courtesyVal)];
overallVal = correspondence[Math.floor(overallVal)];
```

Assign string values to to variables `courtesyVal` and `overallVal`.

This would be okay, but below these lines you check if these values are equal to numbers between 0 and 5. To fix this problem, you could either change the above 2 lines to:

```
courtesyVal = Math.floor(courtesyVal);
overallVal = Math.floor(overallVal);
```

OR you could just get rid of all of your if-statements, since the way you set `courtesyVal` and `overallVal` is correctly getting the `'correspondence'` values.

Here is a fiddle with some sample data and the second option: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/3V2KT/).

If this is not what you were looking for, I'd be happy to try again!

Comment: Hello, based on my data, the average for courtesyVal should be 2, thus D and overallVal should be 2.4, thus D.  But I'm getting output of courtesyVal = A and overallVal = F.  Very weird.